# Swift declare generic protocol by "="

Tags: swift, swift-protocols

```swift
@available(iOS 13.0, macOS 10.15, tvOS 13.0, watchOS 6.0, *)
public protocol ObservableObject : AnyObject {

    /// The type of publisher that emits before the object has changed.
    associatedtype ObjectWillChangePublisher : Publisher = ObservableObjectPublisher where Self.ObjectWillChangePublisher.Failure == Never

    /// A publisher that emits before the object has changed.
    var objectWillChange: Self.ObjectWillChangePublisher { get }
}

final public class ObservableObjectPublisher : Publisher {...}
```

what doese `= ObservableObjectPublisher` mean ?

I kown ":" means , type `ObjectWillChangePublisher` conform to protocol `Publisher`。
But I've never seen using '=' after `associatedtype`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just the way to set a default for an associated type—not unlike setting a default for an argument.

For example, without the `= Never` below,  would not conform to `Protocol`.

```swift
protocol Protocol {
  associatedtype Associatedtype = Never
}

enum : Protocol { }
enum : Protocol {
  typealias Associatedtype = Void
}
```

We're provided the flexibility to conform to `ObservableObject` without `ObjectWillChangePublisher` being `ObservableObjectPublisher`. But anecdotally, I never see any code not using that default.

Comment: thank you. The question made everyone laugh.

I have seen "=" in something implement protocol , not in declare protocol.
now I kown, It is setting a default for an associated type